# How to enable GPU in XGBoost on apple M1 Pro chipset

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I tried using GPU on XGBoost training on windows with device = cuda it worked and training time reduced drastically now i want to do this experiment on my Mac M1 Pro.

How to enable GPU for XGBoost on m1 pro chip set.

I tried looking into documentation where i was unable to find information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently XGBoost doesn't support MPS which is Mac's internal "GPU". To use GPU acceleration, you need to get CUDA gpus.

[image: XGBoost Supported Devices]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).